# Microsoft Date and time picker control 6.0 not firing event on update

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working on a Microsoft access application where I would like to add a date picker and every time the user select a date I would like to trigger an event

[image]

Now as you see in the code I have write a msgbox for testing purpose :

```
Private Sub DTPicker2_Updated(Code As Integer)
MsgBox "EVAN BHOPS"
End Sub
```

But nothing is being triggered even thought I have used breakpoint and closed and opened application

Why? and How to counter this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the `Change` event.

```
Private Sub DTPicker2_Change()
    MsgBox "EVAN BHOPS"
End Sub
```